# Why can't I connect to my SQL Server Express database from a .NET website running on IIS Express in Windows 11 ARM on M1 Macbook using Parallels

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, apple-m1, parallels

I am running Windows 11 ARM on my Macbook with M1 processor using Parallels. I can connect to my SQL Server Express database from development tools like Visual Studio (ARM) and Rider (ARM). Also running a WPF application connecting to the database is no problem.

But if a run a website which wants to connect using the exact same connection string I'm getting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 56 - Unable to load the SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified in the registry. Verify that the Local Database Runtime feature of SQL Server Express is properly installed.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): %1 is not a valid Win32 application

My website is running on .NET framework 4.6.1

Connection string: `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\XXX.mdf;Initial Catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I tried everything now but without result :)

Comment: Consider details like - cough - the connection string and provider used, you know. Maybe that would sort of enable us to sort of help? "The same connection string" does not necessarily mean anything.

Comment: Whow, you are aware that attach is off for like a decade now and that you are NOT USING EXPRESS BUT LOCALDB?

Comment: Problem with bitness here? Try switching between 32bit/64bit in the IIS Express settings. (I just assume it behaves this way also on ARM plattforms).

Comment: What's in the event viewer? I bet there are some security exceptions that the IIS USER doesn't have permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing to find in the event viewer.

Comment: See [Unable to load SQLUserInstance.dll from the location specified... #1752](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1752) which says, _LocalDB is not fully supported on Windows11 ARM64 and there are other users having the same problem on Windows 11. This is not SqlClient issue. The SQLUserInstance.dll is installed while you install SQLLocalDB. To give more detail on this, the mentioned dll is made for x64 architecture, thus is not compatible on ARM 64._